# Error TS2339: What's the difference when using Array vs ReadonlyArray?

Tags: typescript

Can someone explain the difference between Array and ReadonlyArray for the following use case?

Array works fine:

```
function example(text: string | string[]): string[] {
  if (Array.isArray(text)) {
    return text.map(s => s.trim());
  }
  return [text.trim()];
}
```

However ReadonlyArray throws `ts2339` - `Property 'trim' does not exist on type 'string | readyonly string[]`. Why?

```
function example(text: string | ReadonlyArray<string>): string[] {
  if (Array.isArray(text)) {
    return text.map(s => s.trim());
  }
  return [text.trim()];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's...surprising behavior, and it's [discussed in issue #17002](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17002#issuecomment-314108464). Apparently, `Array.isArray` isn't sufficient for TypeScript to narrow the type of `text` from `string | ReadonlyArray<string>` to `string`, even though it works for narrowing `string | string[]`. See the full issue thread for details, but basically it's because `Array.isArray` isn't defined in `readonly` terms.

You can work around it in your case using `typeof`:

```
function example(text: string | ReadonlyArray<string>): string[] {
  if (typeof text === "string") {
    return [text.trim()];
  }
  return text.map(s => s.trim());
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4EMC2AHANsgCijSgC5EBnKAJxjAHNEAfRAJWXQBMFcBPAQWrV0vADxVaDAHwBKchLr0A2gF1EAbwBQiRDGCIivbMjj7iqKIgC8NxACIFDOzI3adiasighqSJeagAOhoYTAIZFQBuNwBfN09vX0QAwMx0bAIKaylKYNowmRlomKA)

Alternatively, you can do as [jcalz suggests here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17002#issuecomment-313719111) and modify the `ArrayConstructor` interface to specify behavior for `isArray` for `readonly` arrays:

```
interface ArrayConstructor {
    isArray<T>(arg: ReadonlyArray<T> | T): arg is ReadonlyArray<T>;
}
```

With that, your original code works just fine - [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSnAngYQPYgDOYUArgmHlMgN4BQyjywh6mWAPACoB8AFHCgBzAFzIAShDgATAgBssbbNx7IAPsi4BKMYKHNCEqbJAKlnXgG46AXzp0YpEBWAFkEAB5wAtgAc5EHyQHmBixFCg+hqSMvKKGMrhkTw6yEkgQgDaALq0DMwwyHzmAHQs5kGeYFpaeUzIUBBgpFAgyMFgJd5wvnyGALyqhCUkwN58NdaMdoyNza3ImR0jEeNa2dY2QA)

Later in the issue thread, though, he says

> I would probably do this if I wanted a workaround:
>
> ```
> interface ReadonlyArrayConstructor  {
>     new(arrayLength?: number): ReadonlyArray<any>;
>     new <T>(arrayLength: number): ReadonlyArray<T>;
>     new <T>(...items: T[]): ReadonlyArray<T>;
>     (arrayLength?: number): ReadonlyArray<any>;
>     <T>(arrayLength: number): ReadonlyArray<T>;
>     <T>(...items: T[]): ReadonlyArray<T>;
>     isArray(arg: any): arg is ReadonlyArray<any>;
>     readonly prototype: ReadonlyArray<any>;
> }
> const ReadonlyArray = Array as ReadonlyArrayConstructor;
> ```
>
> And then later
>
> ```
> if (ReadonlyArray.isArray(immutable)) {
>   const x = immutable; // ReadonlyArray<T>
> } 
> if (immutable instanceof ReadonlyArray) {
>   const x = immutable; //  ReadonlyArray<T>
> }
> ```

In your case, that would be the `ReadonlyArrayConstructor` from the above and

```
function example(text: string | ReadonlyArray<string>): string[] {
  if (ReadonlyArray.isArray(text)) {
    return text.map(s => s.trim());
  }
  return [text.trim()];
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoTgEwPYgDYCeAglFHAQMK4DOYUArgmNlMsgN4BQbbIEA7gAo4pcgBkIIAOZgAFgH4AXMhD0AtgCNoASmXosuQiTIEAPHBAEAfAG5uPPv2SmAKleGiCE6XOWrNOnoYOPjEnq629rwCzm6CAHSJwJBq1MouANoAurpowYZhJhF2PMgeJt4yCn7qWlC5%20iFG4RbWJTwR5eKSVTUB9UEGocbkxVGx7onxyRCp6dkN%20cPhbu1swNQjBB5Syq25IlLIG3lDzUWtkaVQS4TIAA5Q2MxgBPcQg02Fo5d2AL6cBA0MCnL5bZAAXmQ4Lg1FBBS2VBAtAYTBYdk4MHoICYwFwyAgAA84Gp7ngIIJIISwMoUaAjgAfeHLIp06RWXJsqTZDj2YAwMqNBGeaabTyUolgbTaXnXCBgehQEDIKlgeJqOD3QRwiFWZDUeJ0YBqQTS9oAtg3BVK5AZVWGqDG01Zf5AA)